# How to make method, which is repeating every second in c# forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Uhm.. hello,
After year I tried c# without any tutorials. I made a calculator.. everything is works fine, but I want to add more things to it.. For example: when you use your numpad, it will work as well. But that's the problem.. I remember, that in Unity it was ***public void onUpdate()***. But in forms.. it does not work. How to make method, which is updating every second and checking for example `if bool is true`. BTW, `public void Update()` does not work as well.. Where should I type it ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Update` method is specific to the Unity engine and therefore does not work on WinForms. What you want is a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=net-5.0).